# Facebook invite limited number of friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, invite

Is it possible to invite only a limited number of friends to an app?

lets say i want the user to be able to invite only 3 friends. is this possible?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/

I m looking at the reference. but i dont see any thing related to limit number of request.

can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is for an old FBML-based feature that doesn't exist any more.

The current documentation for Requests is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

To answer your question specifically, you can use the `max_recipients` parameter of the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to stop the user from inviting more than a particular number of friends

Note that if you're giving some sort of bonus for users accepting the requests you should also implement logic in your own app which tracks the number and IDs of the sent requests to corelate them later when processing the acceptances, as users could conceivably trigger the dialog themselves via javascript or the popup dialog and send more requests than your app allows